# Solving for Tan[x] = y/z in the range of $x = 0$ and $\pi/2$

Tags: equation-solving

I feel this should be simple

```
Reduce[Tan[x] ==  y/z && 0 < x && x < \[Pi]/2 && y > 0 && 
  z > 0, x, Reals]
```

should return

x = ArcTan(y/z)

However, it returns something apparently equivalent, though much more complex:

```
y > 0 && z > 0 && x == 2*ArcTan[(-z + y*Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2)/y^2])/y]
```

Somehow I'm missing some logic here. Can someone please let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: You already stated your assumptions on `x`, `y` and `z`. If you leave out the `Reals` specification in `Reduce`, it gives you what you want (I'm not sure why, though).

Comment: If you throw an extra `ArcTan[Tan[..]]` around what `x` equals, it simplifies to the desired answer: `y > 0 && z > 0 && 
  x == ArcTan[
    Tan[2 ArcTan[(-z + y Sqrt[(y^2 + z^2)/y^2])/y]]] // FullSimplify`.  I don't see why the desired answer doesn't just happen, even with the domain `Reals`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the form of the solution is designed to exclude imaginary numbers in the output. Excluding Reals from the specification (as suggested by Sjoerd) frees up this requirement.